# How to use tty allocation to run GPG through SSH?

Tags: ssh, tty, gpg

I am trying to encrypt and sign a local file using a distant GPG installation via SSH:

```
pv file | ssh -tt [ssh server] gpg -se -r [receipt key] > file.gpg
```

Using the double *t* option removes the `gpg "cannot open '/dev/tty': No such device or address"` error. However, instead of being sent to the input of gpg, the content to be encrypted is printed right after the ssh password prompt. Then the input is closed, and so it hangs on gpg asking the password to unlock the private key for signing (or the ssh connection is closed if the file is too large).

What is the proper way to pass data to the input of an interactive command executed through SSH?

Answer (score 4):

Piping data into `ssh` (like you did) *is* the right way of passing input data to a command executed via SSH.

The issue here is that `gpg` needs *two* input streams to read from:

- one (STDIN) to read the data to be encrypted,
- another one (the interactive terminal `/dev/tty`) to read the passphrase (which is why you need to pass the `-t` option to `ssh`).

If you conflate the two and try to use STDIN for both purposes, then a way to signal EOF is needed to separate the two inputs.  However, `ssh` would read the end-of-file too, and close the forwarded input stream.

The only practical workaround I can imagine is
save the data to a file and then encrypt it using `gpg` (requires *two* separate `ssh` invocations)::

```
pv file | ssh ... '(umask 077; cat > file.unencrypted)'
ssh -t ... 'gpg -se -r ... < file.unecrypted > file.gpg; rm -f file.unencrypted'
```

Comment: Sure, but the idea here was to avoid "scp-ing" the file to the server, when no hard drive space is available for example...